# SFTP, SSH Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

My sftp -v to host returns,

```
Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xx...
OpenSSH_3.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xx [xxx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.9p1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xxx.xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:63
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@xxx.xx.xx.xx's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Read from remote host xxx.xx.xx.xx: Connection reset by peer
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 61 bytes in 0.0 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 60334.5
debug1: Exit status -1
```

This only occurs with this user. I created a test user which works and other existing users don't have and issue (well no reported issues by users).

Comment: Does "su - user" happily work on the remote server ?

Comment: @Steve yes it does.

Comment: `OpenSSH_3.9p1`? Where did you find such old version? You should update to something more recent. Now we ship OpenSSH-7.2p2`!

Comment: @Jakuje unable to upgrade on Rhel 5.3 (Beta).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer by narcisgarcia @ http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1482005 solved my problem.

Summary: "Owner of the destination directory must be "root", and group/other users cannot have write permissions."